# Help troubleshooting TurtleBot arm interactive markers

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-fuerte, turtlebot-arm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I can't expect anyone to hold the golden key here, but I hope people can suggest what I might do to figure out where the error is.

Previously **Ubuntu 11.10 and Electric was working**.
Currently using Ubuntu 12.04 with **Fuerte... not working yet**.
I can use the arm's interactive markers in the "joint mode", but **the "trajectory mode" gives errors.**

It appears code in ROS is outdated, so I am using the arbotix code from `svn checkout http://vanadium-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ vanadium-ros-pkg-read-only` and arm code from `git clone -b fuerte-devel https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_arm.git`. Both were ok on electric.

When I try moving the gripper, here are the messages I get from the marker server...

```
roslaunch turtlebot_arm_interactive_markers arm_markers.launch
...
core service [/rosout] found
process[turtlebot_arm_marker_server-1]: started with pid [4157]
[ INFO] [1371014595.011226032]: [turtlebot arm marker server] Initialized.
[ INFO] [1371014771.673044255]: Finished in state [ABORTED]
[ INFO] [1371014849.828211285]: Finished in state [ABORTED]
```

Also, I get some weird output from the arm server (there's an error val at bottom, and appears to have no plan)...

```
core service [/rosout] found
process[environment_server-1]: started with pid [3306]
process[planning_scene_validity_server-2]: started with pid [3307]
process[arm_kinematics-3]: started with pid [3309]
process[simple_arm_server-4]: started with pid [3314]
process[reset_arm_server-5]: started with pid [3368]
process[relax_arm_server-6]: started with pid [3376]
[ INFO] [1371014531.525485648]: Environment server started
[ INFO] [1371014532.206517619]: Successfully connected to planning scene action server for /planning_scene_validity_server
[ INFO] [1371014532.413203478]: Successfully connected to planning scene action server for /arm_kinematics
[INFO] [WallTime: 1371014533.593215] simple_arm_server node started
[INFO] [WallTime: 1371014771.458778] Parsing move to:
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: arm_base_link
pose: 
  position: 
    x: 0.00575924804434
    y: -8.69042996783e-05
    z: 0.384833902121
  orientation: 
    x: -0.00553457715202
    y: -0.721403773506
    z: -0.00530987136779
    w: 0.692472215538
roll 0
solution: 
  joint_state: 
    header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: ''
    name: []
    position: []
    velocity: []
    effort: []
  multi_dof_joint_state: 
    stamp: 
      secs: 0
      nsecs: 0
    joint_names: []
    frame_ids: []
    child_frame_ids: []
    poses: []
error_code: 
  val: -27
```

Here are all the nodes/commands I run

```
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal_arm.launch
rosrun turtlebot_dashboard turtlebot_dashboard, set full mode, enable breaker
roslaunch turtlebot_arm_bringup arm.launch
roslaunch turtlebot_arm_bringup simple_arm_server.launch 
rosrun turtlebot_interactive_markers turtlebot_marker_server
roslaunch turtlebot_arm_interactive_markers arm_markers.launch
rosrun rviz rviz
```

THANK YOU!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64877/help-troubleshooting-turtlebot-arm-interactive-markers/) by [dougbot01](https://answers.ros.org/users/2842/dougbot01/) on ROS Answers with karma: 342 on 2013-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, the -27 for error_code, can be decoded by looking at the message for arm_navigation: http://ros.org/doc/api/arm_navigation_msgs/html/msg/ArmNavigationErrorCodes.html

-27 apparently == FRAME_TRANSFORM_FAILURE

Which I presume means you have some sort of TF problem.

Is your turtlebot arm on a turtlebot? After electric, with the release of turtlebot 2, much (if not all) of turtlebot core stacks got completely ripped up and changed -- and so something in the URDF might not be properly connected, or some joint state may not be published.

In addition, with the move to MoveIt, arm_navigation is really no longer maintained or developed (and MoveIt was not really ready for users until Groovy). Unfortunately, this combo leaves the Fuerte turtlebot_arm a bit of a mess.

I've recently started to move the turtlebot_arm to Groovy/MoveIt, with a custom ikfast plugin to replace my hacky old simple_arm_server. Unfortunately it is just a side project, and so progress has been intermittent.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dougbot01](https://answers.ros.org/users/2842/dougbot01/) on 2013-06-12**:
Thank you @fergs for checking. It's on a Turtlebot, and RViz didn't report TF errors. I will set up an arm only URDF for testing. If that doesn't work, I'm assuming it would be a change to the ros-fuerte-simple-arms stack, since the arbotix and turtlebot_arm code are the same (AFAIK). Thanks!

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-06-12**:
l don't recall there being any real updates to simple_arms in Fuerte (I was very late to adopt Fuerte, trying to stay on stable Electric for quite some time, and then jumped to Groovy pretty quickly).

**Comment by [dougbot01](https://answers.ros.org/users/2842/dougbot01/) on 2013-06-12**:
I tried an arm only URDF, with the top plate as the base_link (otherwise it was throwing some errors for multi-dof joints?). Even with that, still no luck... same errors as before. I would love to figure it out, but for now I will have to go back to 11.10/Electric. Thanks for the feedback @fergs !!